# Add configuration directory to classpath using spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I would like to add a configuration directory to the classpath for  a spring boot application at start up, so it can load xml files from the configuration directory.

ie /var/application/config contains
test.xml, dev.xml

The xml will contain mapping information that is required by the application; this is different from application.properties.

I would like to load them at startup.

I am using ClassPathResource to load the files.

Please advise.

Comment: What do the XML files contain? Custom application data that you will be using in other parts of your application?

Answer (score 4):

You can define your own `classpath` by the command-line. Lets suppose your jar is `myapp.jar` and you wand add one extra directory `/var/application/config/`, so you can execute with the following command line:

```
java -cp myapp.jar:/var/application/config/ -Dloader.main=myapp.Application org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
```

ps: if you are using Windows use `;` instead of `:` to separate your `classpath` items.

Answer (score -1):

From the [Spring Boot Reference Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files), add your config location:

`java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/var/application/config/`

Comment: This tells spring where to find configuration files, but does not add the containing folder to the classpath as the OP wishes.

Comment: Specifically, it does not work for non-Spring resources, e.g. logback.xml